# How to get unique set of words from an array by removing duplicates using python

Tags: python, list, set

Below is the array of words I'm having

```
l = ['Australian Cricket Team',
     'Cricket Team Australian',
     'Won Against England',
     'Against England Team']
```

And I want to make it That has only unique words. Below is how I want it to be after processing

```
['Australian', 'Cricket' ,'Team', 'Won',  'Against', 'England']
```

---

Simply I want to have unique set of words.

Comment: You've used the pandas and nltk tags. Are you actually using these libraries? If so please add your code. I'm removing the tags for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a loop:

```
l = ['Australian Criket Team', 'Cricket Team Australian', 'Won Against England', 'Against England Team']

set(w for s in l for w in s.split())
```

Output: `{'Against', 'Australian', 'Cricket', 'Criket', 'England', 'Team', 'Won'}`

Or, if order matters:

```
list(dict.fromkeys(w for s in l for w in s.split()))
```

Output: `['Australian', 'Criket', 'Team', 'Cricket', 'Won', 'Against', 'England']`

###### functional variant

```
from itertools import chain
set(chain.from_iterable(map(str.split, l)))
```

Comment: Is the output generating with this code? I dont get any output! Can you help

Comment: @Nick you need to assign to a variable, or print. Example: `out = set(w for s in l for w in s.split()) ; print(out)`

Comment: Yes that worked! What if I want to get the out put as below?
['Australian Criket', 'Team Cricket', 'Won Against', 'England']

Comment: @Nick then you need to [split the output list by chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> ```
> def unique(list1):
>  
>     # initialize a null list
>     unique_list = []
>      
>     # traverse for all elements
>     for x in list1:
>         # check if exists in unique_list or not
>         if x not in unique_list:
>             unique_list.append(x)
>     # print list
>     for x in unique_list:
>         print x,
> ```

original post at [GeekforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-get-unique-values-list/) https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-get-unique-values-list/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).